# Assign different actions for two radio buttons in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, radio-button

I am a newbie in html and js. I have been trying to check possible discussions about my problem, but couldn't find anything similar.

Here is my problem: I need to have two radio buttons and I would like to show different buttons for each radio button selection that could take the page further actions (i.e. if radio button A selected, show exit button, if radio button B selected show next button. In this direction, I started to create something, but I stuck at the point of creating conditional actions.

In my php file I have the following codes:

```
    <div>
    <label><input type="radio" id="noc" name="c" value="f_c" onchange="disp_button(this.checked);"> no action</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" id="co" name="c" value="t_c" onchange="disp_button(this.checked);"> take action</label><br>
    </div>

    <div class="header_format"><p id="hidden_field" style="display:none;" <input onclick="do_this();" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Continue" />Next</button></div></p>
    <div class="header_format"><p id="hidden" style="display:none;" <input onclick="do_that();" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Exit" />Exit</button></div></p>
```

in addition to the js file, which contains the functions for php file. I defined specific function for my radio button actions like that below in my js file:

```
function disp_button(checked){
        var button1 = document.getElementById("noc");
        var button2 = document.getElementById("co");

        if (button1.checked){
            show_exit_button("noc radio button selected");
        }else if (button2.checked) {
            show_next_button("co radio button selected");
        }
}
```

So, I would appreciate any help to put those things together. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have a css file which contains php functions as javascript? .-.

Comment: @LuisE it was actually js file contains the functions for my php file. I edited my post. Thanks for the question.

Comment: I dont understand what the question is... your function seems "pseudocodically" correct (I do not have the code of "show_next_button").

Comment: I'm afraid you can't use PHP functions in JavaScript. PHP lives on the server and JavaScript on the client, so you'll need to write your functions in JavaScript if you want something to happen to your page on the client. There are many examples of how to accomplish this.

Comment: I was trying to create a function to show different buttons for each radio button selection, but I don't know exactly what coding would work inside that if_else statement, since I have almost zero background on php, js, html.

Comment: Do not tell anyone I did this, but I would have liked for someone to give me some examples when I was learning... https://jsfiddle.net/1azn6e03/